# mod_geoip in local

Tags: ip, localhost, apache-http-server

I have to implement a geo location functionality on a Magento based website, thus php on an apache2 server.
Obviously, in my local machine mod_geoip isn't very helpful. I was wondering if I could *fool* apache somehow so that I could make some test locally, ie having another IP than 127.0.0.1 returned, but at the same time my local website should still run.

Is it possible? If yes, I'd appreciate some guidance or a link to an explanation.
thanks